# Why can I not get a React HTML5 video component to Play?

Tags: html, reactjs, npm, html5-video, rendering

I was attempting to add a continuous HTML5 Video loop on my home page component of my React application. I used the NPM package "react-html5video" to generate this component. When I launch the app through localhost, it initially looks as if it will play, however I receive the following error inside the div, "Video cannot be played in this browser". I can't seem to figure out what it is that I am doing wrong.

1. Video Component:

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import Video from 'react-html5video';

   export class VideoLoop extends React.Component {
   render () {
   return (
     <Video controls autoPlay loop muted>
       <source
       src="../src/videos/oakmont.mp4"
       type="video/mp4"
       />
     </Video>
     );
    }
   };

   export default VideoLoop;
   ```
2. Home Page Component:

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import VideoLoop from './video_loop';

   export default () => {
   return <div>
           Home Page
           <VideoLoop />
         </div>
   };
   ```
3. Routing

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
   import App from './components/app';
   import PropertyList from './components/property_list';
   import HomePage from './components/home_page';
   import AboutUs from './components/about_us';
   import Contact from './components/contact';


   export default (
   <Route path="/" component={App}>
     <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
     <Route path="properties"  component={PropertyList} />
     <Route path="aboutus"  component={AboutUs} />
     <Route path="contact"  component={Contact} />
   </Route>
   );
   ```

Comment: Have you tried this on multiple browsers?

Comment: Yes, I tried it on chrome, chrome incognito and safari. All returned the same error.

Comment: Are you sure `../src/videos/oakmont.mp4` is pointing to the right video file?

Comment: Check the network tab in devTools to see if the video file was found and loaded

Answer (score 6):

It is quite simple to make a video play in react.

```
// I 
import video from '../src/videos/a.mp4'
//In your component

//Add other tags as necessary
<video src={video}> </video>
```

You don't need any other modules for this.

Comment: What if I need to load a different video depending on props?

Comment: Video is not playing. Only the image is shown.

Comment: This guided me to the right direction: https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/61335/react-video-element-is-not-working-properly

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: Seems it preload the source then can autoPlay at the page!---

```
import React from "react";

import video from '../Video/Teheran.mp4';


       <video controls autoPlay loop muted>
          <source src={video} type="video/mp4" >
          </source>
```